# wrapper class apex pagemessages

Tags: visualforce, wrapper-class

Class:

```
public pagereference updateEngagements(){          
         if(wrapList!=null && wrapList.size()==0 ) { 
         ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'ERROR: Nothing to Update '));
                 return null;  
                 }
         Site__c siteSpecialities =[Select Id,Name,Tracks__c from Site__c WHERE Name=:selectedSite AND Cohort__r.Name=:selectedCohort LIMIT 1];
         try{ 
              list<Engagement__c> enList=new list<Engagement__c>();              
                 for(WrapperClass wr: wrapList){ 
                    if(wr.selectedLC!='' && wr.selectedLC!=null && wr.selectedLC!='--Unassigned--' ){  
                         Engagement__c en= new Engagement__c();
                         en.id = wr.eng.Id; 
                         en.Learning_Community__c= wr.selectedLC;
                         if(JSON.serialize(siteSpecialities.Tracks__c).contains(wr.eng.Track_Assignment__c)){                               
                             wr.specialCheck ='';
                             en.Track_Assignment__c = wr.eng.Track_Assignment__c; 
                         }else {                              
                             wr.specialCheck ='border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; border: 3px solid red;';
                             ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'ERROR: Please select the correct Speciality. Available Specialities for this Site are: '+siteSpecialities.Tracks__c));

                         }
                         enList.add(en);             
                     }  

                 }                  
                 if(enList.size()>0 ){
                     System.debug(enList);
                     itFailed = true;   
                     Database.update(enList);
                     }
                  }

         catch(System.DmlException e){
                 ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'ERROR: ' +e));
                 return null;
             }

         return null;
     }
```

Page:

```
<tbody>
                            <apex:repeat value="{!wrapList}" var="e">
                                <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                                  <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-shrink" data-label="Select row Engagement">
                                    <label class="slds-checkbox">                          
                                      <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!e.selected}" id="inputId" />          
                                      <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
                                      <span class="slds-assistive-text">Select row Engagement</span>
                                    </label>
                                  </td>         
                                  <td role="gridcell" data-label="Account Name">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub"><apex:outputText value="{!e.eng.name}" /></div>
                                  </td> 
                                  <td><apex:outputText value="{!e.eng.Student_Full_Name__c}" id="studentName" /></td>   
                                  <td>
                                    <apex:selectList styleclass="slds-input" value="{!e.selectedLC}" size="1" id="lcoption">                                                                              
                                          <apex:selectOptions value="{!e.selectedCLC}"/> 
                                          <apex:param value="{!e.rowcount}" assignTo="{!count}" name="count"/> 
                                    </apex:selectList>
                                  </td>                   
                                  <td><apex:outputText value="{!e.eng.Prospect_Track_Interest__c }" /></td>  
                                  <td>
                                      <apex:outputPanel id="trackassignment">                                    
                                              <div style="{!e.specialCheck}" class="slds-form-element">                                      
                                              <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-picklist">
                                                <apex:inputfield styleclass="slds-select " value="{!e.eng.Track_Assignment__c}"/>
                                             </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </apex:outputPanel> 
                                  </td>  
                                  <td> 
                                  <apex:outputPanel id="Strackassignment">
                                       <div style="{!e.specialCheck}" class="slds-form-element">                                      
                                              <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-picklist">
                                     <apex:inputfield styleclass="slds-select " value="{!e.eng.Secondary_Specialty_Assignment__c}"/>
                                      </div>
                                       </div>
                                   </apex:outputPanel>      
                                  </td>                                  
                                </tr>  
                            </apex:repeat>
                          </tbody>
```

Issue:

I am printing the error message in case of wr.eng.Track_Assignment__c not matching with siteSpecialities. However I am not using return null, becuase I need to show the red border for each row in case of error. Since I am not using the return null, system is updating the records. How do I stop updating the records if there is a mismatch for one of the records?

Multiple fields:

```
    if(JSON.serialize(siteSpecialities.Tracks__c).contains(wr.eng.Track_Assignment__c)){                               
                                 wr.specialCheck ='';
                                 en.Track_Assignment__c = wr.eng.Track_Assignment__c; 
                             }else {                              
                                 wr.specialCheck ='border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; border: 3px solid red;';
                                 ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'ERROR: Please select the correct Speciality. Available Specialities for this Site are: '+siteSpecialities.Tracks__c));

                             }

if(wr.eng.Secondary_Specialty_Assignment__c !=null && JSON.serialize(siteSpecialities.Tracks__c).contains(wr.eng.Secondary_Specialty_Assignment__c)){  
                                 wr.specialCheck ='';
                                 en.Track_Assignment__c = wr.eng.Secondary_Specialty_Assignment__c; 
                             }else{

                                 wr.specialCheck ='border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; border: 3px solid red;';
                                 ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'ERROR: Please select the correct Speciality. Available Specialities for this Site are: '+siteSpecialities.Tracks__c));

                             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are few different ways you can address this..

one option is to declare a boolean variable with default value false

```
bError = false;
```

then Set a boolean variable to true in the block of code where you set the error message..

```
else {                              
      wr.specialCheck ='border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; border: 3px solid red;';
      ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'ERROR: Please select the correct Speciality. Available Specialities for this Site are: '+siteSpecialities.Tracks__c));
      bError = true;                      
}
```

and in the section where you do the update check if that boolean variable is false

```
if(enList.size()>0 && bError == false){
     System.debug(enList);
     itFailed = true;   
     Database.update(enList);
}
```

the other option is you can directly check the `ApexPages.getMessages()` list and see if its empty or not before doing the update

Comment: That is wonderful idea, however how about incase I have same validation for two fields in the wrapper. Please refer my updated description "Multiple fields". If I use that code, border highlight is not working as expected. Any suggestion?